# Update label text with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, label

I am trying to update the text of this item in jquery, but I can't seem to select it:

```
<label for="ctl00_m_g_29f26907_677f_4b59_92e6_d688d334f136_ctl00_fvMain_DateTo" class="someClass">TEXT</label>




$("label[for$='DateTo']").length //nope
$('label [for$="DateTo"]').length //nope

$('label [for="ctl00_m_g_29f26907_677f_4b59_92e6_d688d334f136_ctl00_fvMain_DateTo"]').length //nothing
```

How can I select (and update the label text) of this html?

**edit** exactly what i type in the [chrome console inside the] jsfiddle...!?

```
$("label[for$='DateTo']").length
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
```

**edit** it must be something to do with the chrome console? I don't get a value but the actual update code works http://jsfiddle.net/e84MG/5/ ... confusing

Comment: `$("label[for$='DateTo']").length` is the correct one given `Blah_Blah` is replaced with `DateTo`

Comment: Remove space between your selectors

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/e84MG/1/ - also make sure to run your script in a dom ready handler

Comment: ummm... chrome is giving me 0 for the exact string in your jsfiddle

Comment: @baron for me chrome is giving 1 in the console

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/e84MG/3/

Comment: `$('label[for$=DateTo]').length`

Comment: looks like `$` is not `jQuery` - try `jQuery("label[for$='DateTo']").length`